# Breadcrumb per content type per role, bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs, bootstrapping

I need to display a breadcrumb per content type and per role. What the best way  to do it. I've tried a lot of module and none fit my needs.

I tried overwritting breadcrumb in template.php as follow, and it's not working :

```
function local_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $output = '';

  global $user;
  /** Breadcrumb for hsrehab_admin **/
  if(in_array('hsrehab_admin', $user->roles)) {
   if ($vars['node']->type == 'patient_sheet') {
     // Build Breadcrumbs
     $breadcrumb = array();
     $breadcrumb[] = l('Dashboard', '');
     $breadcrumb[] = l('Manage Patients', '/admin/manage-patients');
     $breadcrumb[] = l(drupal_get_title(), base_path() . request_uri());
     }
   }

  // Determine if we are to display the breadcrumb.
  $bootstrap_breadcrumb = bootstrap_setting('breadcrumb');
  if (($bootstrap_breadcrumb == 1 || ($bootstrap_breadcrumb == 2 && arg(0) == 'admin')) && !empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $output = theme('item_list', array(
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('breadcrumb container'),
      ),
      'items' => $breadcrumb,
      'type' => 'ol',
    ));
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: can you modify the breadcrumbs in the template for each content type?

Comment: I don't know, that's a good question. Should I make a module ?

Comment: Which modules did you try?

Comment: And can you start with a simpler version of the code above, where the breadcrumb is always altered no matter the user role and node type? Just to see if it works.

Comment: Hey, I finally used [Path bredcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) and succeed to do what I wanted. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a theme template for each content type, then add the breadcrumb logic in there and output the modified breadcrumb there. Here's a great [DO resource for theming](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440) and how to use template files. In a nutshell, you can clone your default page.tpl.php and rename it page--patient_sheet.tpl.php and inside this template you can run and output the breadcrumb logic.